# Invalid object name after restoring a database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, restore

i have my c# application, and i want to restore a database using my application . my sql code is like this:

```
alter database SSDPrototypeV3 set offline with rollback immediate
restore database SSDPrototypeV3
from disk = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\dustinepogi.bak'
alter database SSDPrototypeV3 set online
```

when i run this on my application, it successfully restores my db . but when i try to run a sql query (like a select statement), it says that i have an invalid object name, specifically on the table that i performed my select statement . but then, if i reload my application after closing, it is fully restored . how can i get rid of this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using [`SqlClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.aspx) (and you are using connection pooling):

- switch to master first
- do your restore
- **clean your connection pool**: using [`SqlConnection.ClearAllPools`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools.aspx) (clears all pools for the provider) or [`ClearPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool.aspx) (clears just the pool associated with the specific connection string)
- run your commands against your original database

And, hopefully, off you go

Answer (score 0):

A database connection has a *current database* that all queries are executed against. The *initial database* parameter of the connection string determines the current database used when the connection is opened.

I assume that the current database changes back to `master` when you take your `SSDPrototypeV3` database offline. You have two options to fix this:

- Change the current database back by executing `use SSDPrototypeV3` or
- close and reopen the connection.

Comment: i've tried closing the connection on my application, and switched it to master, but i still got the same problem/error .

Comment: @DustineTolete: You shouldn't switch to `master`, you should switch to your DB! Does `select * from SSDPrototypeV3.dbo.someTable` work?